# How can I track user progress of an articulate presentation (SCORM/TinCan) using php

Tags: php, tracking, scorm, tin-can-api

I have some SCORM or TinCan compliant presentations made using Articulate Studio or Articulate Storyline.

I want to integrate those presentations into a simple php LMS I made. I need to be able to track user progress. Right now I can tell when people click on the link to the presentation but I do not know if they finished viewing it. I am not familiar with SCORM/TinCan but I think there is a way of tracking the user progress. At least other LMS like Chamilo can import these presentations and they keep track of the user progress.

Anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a SCORM or Tincan (XAPI) engine is a very big project by itself. You can try building one on your own, but be prepared to spend months on it. If you decide this, I would strongly recommend to go with tincan, which I expect to evolve to be the standard in a few years (although it's not widely supported yet).

Alternatively, a very nice solution would be to [Rustici's scorm engine](http://scorm.com/), wich is a great implementation that supports all versions of SCORM and tincan (but not free, as @Trip noted)

I also believe that there are open source implementations of these, but I haven't tried any myself.

Comment: Rustici's scorm engine is not free. Its actually really expensive. But from my understanding TinCan can be implemented independently and you can record that data using ( maybe? ) TinCan.js as a tracker to your app.

Comment: @Trip You are correct, it is not free for non-commercial use as I had thought (obviously I was thinking about SCORM cloud), thanks for pointing out!

Comment: SCORM Cloud for non-Tin Can usage (aka SCORM) isn't free, but it is metered (amount of usage based) and has a PHP library for implementing directly with your PHP based app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try LRS like [GrassBlade LRS](http://www.nextsoftwaresolutions.com/grassblade-lrs-experience-api/). If you are using your own LMS you might need to do the launch part yourself. However, if you are open to use platforms like WordPress, you have a nice option like [GrassBlade xAPI Companion](http://www.nextsoftwaresolutions.com/grassblade-xapi-companion/).